# How to convert persistent entities to concrete types in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns

I have a code structure like below.. I know this example is bit weird, but the entities I am working on are similar in structure.

```
interface IAnimal 
{
    string name {get; set;}
    int Age { get; set;}
    string AnimalType { get; set;}
    ICollection<Dependent> Dependents{get; set;}
}

interface IDependent : IAnimal
{

    string RelationshipToParent{get; set;}
}

class Dependent : IDependent
{
    public string name { get; set;}
    public int Age { get; set;}
    public string AnimalType { get; set;}
    public string RelationshipToParent { get; set;}
    public ICollection<Dependent> Dependents { get; set;}
}

class Animal : IAnimal
{
    public string name { get; set;}
    public int Age { get; set;}
    public string AnimalType{get; set;}
    public ICollection<Dependent> Dependents { get; set;}
}


class Tiger : IAnimal
{
    public string name { get; set;}
    public int Age { get; set;}
    public string AnimalType{get; set;}
    public ICollection<Dependent> Dependents { get; set;}
}

class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string name { get; set;}
    public int Age{ get; set;}
    public string AnimalType{get; set;}
    public ICollection<Dependent> Dependents{ get; set;}
}

class DogDependent : Dependent
{

}

class TigerDependent : Dependent
{

}
```

Animal can have dependents as any other animal(eg..Tiger can have dependents as Dog and Elephant)
Animal and Dependent classes are the persistent entities in SQL server(using Entity Framework).
My problem is I have approx 20 such concrete Animals.. After reading the entity from DB, I need a sophisticated way to convert Animal to concrete types like Tiger,Dog,etc.. based on AnimalType property.

example..
If AnimalType of Animal oobject is "Tiger" then Animal should be converted into Tiger type(with all the properties). Same goes with dependents as well, If Dependent of that Animal type is Dog, then Dependent should be converted into DogDependent.

Is there a better way to do this rather than writing a mapper for each type?

Comment: Please provide some form of compileable code. You have interfaces with fields, class member fields without type and so on. Makes it hard to separate the pseudo-issues from your actual problem.

Comment: @grek40 updated the code

Comment: A few thing I don't understand about your code: Interfaces are supposed to describe behavior, that is, the actions that your object can do. According to this Animal should be a class, and maybe abstract. Your concrete animal doesn't add any functionality over the base animal, so I don't think it's necessary, you could just use a base animal and keep the concrete animal as an attribute of the animal. All this would simplify the above model to only two classes.

Comment: @klink there is behavior defined in the interfaces, for the sake of example purpose, I have removed the functions in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what your are asking is how to map your object model to a relational model, right? If this is the case then there are many patterns to do this.
If you have you data model already defined and all your concrete animals (Tiger, Elephant, etc) are in the same table then the easiest strategy to use would be One Table per Concrete Class. All you have to do is add a discriminator column to differentiate each type and tell EF how to map each record to a specific class based on this.

There are many articles that describes the different strategies, this is one:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your mapping will differ depending on table per type or table per hierarchy.

> Is there a better way to do this rather than writing a mapper for each type?

It depends, if all your types have additional properties you will need to map them. If you only want to capture behavior in the class but the structure is the same then you do not have to map each type.

Here is an example where you could use a single table across your types. Currently the types are hardcoded using a string to discriminate between types. You could also use an enumeration and you could also add some reflection to automatically add your known types and their discriminators to the mapping at run time based on a custom attribute (for example).

```
public sealed class DependentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Dependent>
{
    internal DependentMap()
    {
        Map(configuration => configuration.MapInheritedProperties());
        this.ToTable("DependentAnimals").HasKey(t => t.DependentId); // making up some table name and pk here

        // mapping types
        // you could probably also map this using reflection if you structure your concrete types to include some type of indicator
        Map<DogDependent>(configuration => configuration.Requires("AnimalType").HasValue("Dog");
        Map<TigerDependent>(configuration => configuration.Requires("AnimalType").HasValue("Tiger");
    }
}
```

Some dbContext access

```
db.Set<TigerDependent>().Single(x => name == "Tony the Tiger");
```

---

*Disclaimer: I did not do anything with your interfaces as EF is not designed to work directly with them. The design of EF is to work directly with concrete types (ie. classes) as the model.*